# How do I extract two arrays from a JSON with nested objects

Tags: reactjs, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate a menu and a sub menu in ReactJs. The data comes from an external api in JSON format.

Here's the JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "content": "A",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "1"
            },
            {
                "content": "2"
            },
            {
                "content": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "content": "B",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "10"
            },
            {
                "content": "20"
            },
            {
                "content": "30"
            },
            {
                "content": "40"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "content": "C",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "X"
            },
            {
                "content": "Y"
            },
            {
                "content": "Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to generate two arrays from the above JSON data, similar to the ones below:

```
Array1 = ["A","B","C"]

Array2 = {
            A: ["1", "2", "3"],
            B: ["10", "20", "30", "40"],
            C: ["X", "Y", "Z"]
        };
```

How can I achieve that ? Thanks.

Comment: What you are calling `Array2` is not an array, it's an object. Did you try anything? If you don't specify what you have tried, we can only do your work for you instead teaching you a lesson. `Array1` is easily achieved with `json.map(o => o.content)`. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Use the knowledge from my suggestion above to create the object you want. You may want to use `Array#reduce` instead of mapping

Comment: You are correct, Array2 is an object. I have tried using the reduce function, but didn't seem to have achieved on creating the second object.

Comment: Then why didn't you post what you have tried so far? That is one of the basic tenets of asking good questions, as explained in the link above. Then we can tell you what your problem was instead of just writing a solution for you, as the existing answers do, they're not helping you understand what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter an object uniquely, the best way is to create an object with that unique key and keep on appending data to that unique key something like below.

```js
const obj = {}
  const data = [
    {
        "content": "A",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "1"
            },
            {
                "content": "2"
            },
            {
                "content": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "content": "B",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "10"
            },
            {
                "content": "20"
            },
            {
                "content": "30"
            },
            {
                "content": "40"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "content": "C",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "X"
            },
            {
                "content": "Y"
            },
            {
                "content": "Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]

data.forEach(el => obj[el.content] = el.Subtypes.map(e => e.content));
console.log(obj);
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Comment: @JuanMendes Updated. Changed from `map()` function to `forEach()` as it causes an eslint error for returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need because you mentioned two arrays and the array2 in your example is an object

```
const firstArray = [],
    secondArray = [];

json.forEach(({
    content,
    Subtypes
}) => {
    firstArray.push(content);
    secondArray.push(Subtypes.map(({
        content
    }) => content));
});
```

if you meant an object for the second array, you can update it to

```
secondArray[content] = Subtypes.map(({content}) => content);
```

Comment: Please don't call an object an array! Also, there are a million ways to do this, you should let the OP give it a real try instead of just doing their work for them. Teach them how to fish.

Comment: @JuanMendes I understand what you want to imply, next time I will do that :)

re: calling object an array -
Just referencing the OP current examples and i'm not paying more attention to that.

Answer (score 1):

below code give the output you desired,var ff is the array

```
ff.reduce((accm, cv, cidx, arr) => {
   accm.array1.push(cv.content);
   accm.array2[cv.content] = cv.Subtypes.map(t => t.content);
   return accm;
}, { array1: [], array2: {} });
```

Comment: Why add another solution? There are two answers that solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example code written in typescript that gives the above-mentioned output.

```js
let s = [
    {
        "content": "A",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "1"
            },
            {
                "content": "2"
            },
            {
                "content": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "content": "B",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "10"
            },
            {
                "content": "20"
            },
            {
                "content": "30"
            },
            {
                "content": "40"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "content": "C",
        "Subtypes": [
            {
                "content": "X"
            },
            {
                "content": "Y"
            },
            {
                "content": "Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]



type subType = {
    [k: string]: any
}
let contentList: string[] = []
let obj: subType = {};
s.forEach((c) => {
    contentList.push(c.content);
    obj[c.content] = [];
    c.Subtypes.forEach((e) => {
         obj[c.content].push(e.content);
    });
})

console.log(obj)
console.log(contentList)
```